# Echo message is blank after POST request to server

Tags: c#, php, winforms

**Code:**

```
private async Task httpAsync()
{

    var data = new StringContent("1254", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var url = "https://mywebsite.com/insert.php";
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    textBox2.Text = result;
}

private async void button3_AsyncClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await httpAsync();
}
```

**My insert.php script:**

```
<?php

 $postdata = $_GET['data'];

 echo $postdata;
?>
```

**The Error I get:**
Notice: Undefined index: data in /storage/ssd3/643/15098643/public_html/insert.php

I am still new to this can someone assist me with this error. I am trying to echo back the "1254" sent to the server, for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about PHP not finding a parameter named 'data' in the request.

First of all, you are mixing up a `POST` request with a `GET` request. It looks like your C# script is posting '1254' to your PHP script, but in your PHP script you are looking for GET parameters in the URL.
So either:

- change your C# script to send a `GET` request
  or
- change your PHP script to check the `POST` request by using $_POST[param name]

Second, your PHP script is looking for a parameter called 'data', but all your C# script is sending is a string with the value '1254'

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-an-http-post-web-request) to see how you can send a `POST` request in C# using parameters.